An example of a left uniform ring with one right ideal not an SIP-module
Recall that a module $M_R$ is called uniform if the intersection of any two nonzero submodules is nonzero. A ring (with $1$) $R$ is called left (resp., right) uniform if the module ${}_RR$ (resp., $R_R$) is uniform.
We say that $M_R$ is an SIP-module if the intersection of any two summands of $M$ is a summand.
I need to construct a ring $R$ with unity with the following properties:

$R$ is left uniform

There exists a right ideal $I \subseteq R$ such that $I_R$ is not an SIP-module


I thought of the ring of left polynomials $R:=k[x;\sigma]$ where $k$ is any field and $\sigma:k\to k$ is a ring monomorphism which is not surjective. The multiplication is defined by $xa=\sigma(a)x$ for every $a\in k$. It's known that $R$ is left uniform. But I don't known whether there exists a right ideal of $R$ which is not an SIP-module.
Also, I thought of the quotient ring $S=R / Rx^2$, where $R$ is the ring mentioned above. This ring is also left uniform. But, up till now, I have no ideal whether $S$ contains a right ideal $I \subseteq S$ which is not an SIP-module.
Any contribution is appreciated.
